# Как создать такой вид при такой HTML структуре?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Привет есть такой вид блоков. Первый блок имеет 50% ширину всего контейнера и 100% высоту. А след 4 блока идут по 25% ширины и 50% высоты.
Внимание на скриншот
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том что мне требуется такая HTML структура, без сторонних Wrapperов

```
<div class="items">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Какими стилями можно подогнать такой вариант разметки

**Пожалуйста без доп библиотек. Требуется чистый HTML**

Comment: [Grid layout](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

Comment: можно...но нужно добавить идентификаторов для индивидуальной настройки на `css`. И что значит "чисты `html`"? вы `css` не собираетесь использовать?

Answer (score 0):

Если без добавления оберток, то `display:` [grid](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.items {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;  
  grid-gap: 0 0;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


.item:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: #03a9f3;
  
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  
}
.item:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: #feeb3c;
}
.item:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: #ff5822;
}
.item:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: #4daf50;
}
.item:nth-of-type(5) {
  background: #9c28b0;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```

Или с помощью [masonry grid](https://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html):

```js
$('.items').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.item',
  percentPosition: true,
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.items {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.grid-sizer {
  width: 25%;
}

.item {
  width: 25%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.item:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: #03a9f3;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.item:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: #feeb3c;
}

.item:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: #ff5822;
}

.item:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: #4daf50;
}

.item:nth-of-type(5) {
  background: #9c28b0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.2.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="items">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно и с float том ))

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.items {
  position: relative;
}
.item {
  outline: 1px solid #f00;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  min-height: 50vh;
  float: left;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
.item-1 {
  outline: 1px solid #f00;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="items">
  <div class="item item-1">width-50%<br>height-100%</div>
  <div class="item item-2">width-25%<br>height-50%</div>
  <div class="item item-3">width-25%<br>height-50%</div>
  <div class="item item-4">width-25%<br>height-50%</div>
  <div class="item item-5">width-25%<br>height-50%</div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```